# Regex unless inside "speech marks"

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

If I wanted to match the below:

```
slashdot               <-Hit

"    slashdot    "     <-Hit

"    slashdot          <-Hit

    slashdot    "      <-Hit

"slashdot"             <-Miss
```

(Incuding if was with no linebreaks) how would I regex that?

I would please like it so that speechmarks cancel a match, but only if there is absolutly no whitespace between the content and the speechmarks.

I found some samples on stackoverflow about how to detect speechmarks

```
(?=(?:(?:[^"]*+"){2})*+[^"]*+\z)
```

But I am having trouble setting them so that if there are any spaces, the hit is still made.

All help very much appreciated. (I am new to stackoverflow and very much like it! I am trying to answer as many questions for others as I can, and learn all I hear)

---

Put simply

```
slashdot - good
"slashdot" - bad
" slashdot " - good (as there are spaces)
```

Comment: Hi - Are you after everything between `" ` and `"`, where there is a space prior and post the quotation marks?

Comment: I would like everything matched to 'slashdot' UNLESS it is inside speechmarks with no spaces

Comment: So 
slashdot - good
"slashdot" - bad
" slashdot " - good (as there are spaces)

Comment: Can i ask if you simply want to strip the quotation marks? As the `bad` portion, or no match, is not really a function of regex. I can write an expression that will return slashdot, but you may need to check the `"slashdot"` prior. If you could provide some context of what you're trying to achieve, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

This regex will only find line with no quotes, or where quotes have white space between the quotes and it's payload. This expression assumes the first non space character would be the quote if it existed. If the first non space character is not the open quote then the entire line is allowed.

`^\s*(?:[^"].*|"\s.*\s"?)\s*(?:$|\r|\n|\Z)`

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

**Input string**

```
slashdot           
"    slashdot    " 
"    multiline 1 slashdot     
    line 2 slashdot    " 
"slashdot bad"        
     "    leading spaces and trailing spaces    "
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/^(?:[^"].*|"\s[^"]*\s")/imx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => slashdot           
        [1] => "    slashdot    " 
        [2] => "    multiline 1 slashdot     
        [3] =>     line 2 slashdot    " 
        [4] =>      "    leading spaces and trailing spaces    " 
         )

)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for all this help. Its very appreciated. I hope I can answer lots of questions for others soon too, as new to stackoverflow but what a community! :)

Comment: +1 for awesome chart. Do you have a tool which produced that?

Comment: @Racheet, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.